# Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:3.2/HTJ85B/XWKL1:user/release-keys' error in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a baseball application. It works fine on Htc Incredible, Samsung 7 inch, but getting crash after playing 3 times only on Samsung 10 inch device. I got the error as:

```
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:3.2/HTJ85B/XWKL1:user/release-keys'
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): pid: 4695, tid: 5082  >>> com.sttl.em <<<
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr fff61dcc
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237):  r0 fff61dcc  r1 00000000  r2 002e1cf0  r3 00000000
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237):  r4 00000de1  r5 81d1a1ac  r6 002e1cf0  r7 00000000
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237):  r8 5e9bfb78  r9 40093f0c  10 40093ef4  fp 4023c078
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237):  ip 00000000  sp 5e9bfb58  lr aff10cb4  pc 81d0e810  cpsr a0000030
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R0:
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): fff61dcc: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): fff61dec: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): fff61e0c: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): fff61e2c: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): fff61e4c: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R2:
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1cf0: 00000505 002de030 00000001 00000010 002d05a8 00000000 00000002 002df088 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d10: 00000000 00000002 002df110 00000000 00000002 00327918 00000000 00000001 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d30: 002d04a8 00000000 00000001 00111f60 00000000 00000001 002b9740 00000000 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d50: 00000001 002b9788 00000000 00000001 002b97d0 00000000 00000001 00274118 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d70: 00000000 00000001 00274160 00000000 00000001 002741a8 00000000 00000001 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R5:
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 81d1a1ac: 00000000 00000000 00000000 80c03744 80c02d90 80c02d98 80c03784 80c05934 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 81d1a1cc: 80c05948 aff188c5 80c0698c aff0cdc8 aff19f95 aff184a1 aff180c1 80c06668 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 81d1a1ec: 80c05a98 80c05940 aff0c8fc 80c05944 80c0665c 80c037a4 aff289a9 80c03764 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 81d1a20c: aff0cc28 aff0d090 aff0cfb4 80c064d4 80c064d8 80c02d94 80c02f10 aff0cef0 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 81d1a22c: aff0cf9c aff1cead 80d04611 80d045d5 80d04631 80d045fd 80d04621 80d045e9 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R6:
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1cf0: 00000505 002de030 00000001 00000010 002d05a8 00000000 00000002 002df088 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d10: 00000000 00000002 002df110 00000000 00000002 00327918 00000000 00000001 
04-18 11:22:34.610: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d30: 002d04a8 00000000 00000001 00111f60 00000000 00000001 002b9740 00000000 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d50: 00000001 002b9788 00000000 00000001 002b97d0 00000000 00000001 00274118 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 002e1d70: 00000000 00000001 00274160 00000000 00000001 002741a8 00000000 00000001 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R8:
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 5e9bfb78: 002fc3a8 00000001 5e9bfc18 40093f08 59110008 002fc3a8 5e9bfb98 aca4120b 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 5e9bfb98: 40093f08 5aae2cd7 ad32c368 5e9bfc18 ad32c368 40093f24 5e9bfc10 00000002 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 5e9bfbb8: 00000000 5c8e871c 00000000 5e9bfc10 00000001 001b35f8 002fc3b0 0001dbc0 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 5e9bfbd8: 00002000 acaa11b8 fffffe90 aca1be20 5e9bfc10 002fc3a8 aca1bd90 592db5c0 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 5e9bfbf8: fffffe78 aca1aed4 00000000 00000000 5e9bfed8 aca16bdc 59a87df4 40093ec8 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R9:
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f0c: 00000de1 40093f40 59014b98 592d9224 5900bd10 5c8f27d9 00000de1 40936d10 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f2c: 40093f64 59014e4c 592d78ac 59014b98 5c8f33c1 00000000 3e828f5d 40852b50 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f4c: 40936d10 40093f88 59022ec4 592d7c54 59014e4c 5c8f2ff5 40b2da68 00000001 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f6c: 40852b50 40936d10 40093fdc 59023338 592db3b0 59022ec4 00000000 40936d10 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f8c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0002dc1a 40936d10 000002f0 00000000 00000500 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): dump around R10:
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093ef4: 40093f24 5900bd10 59110008 001c53b0 5c8efa45 40936d10 00000de1 40093f40 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f14: 59014b98 592d9224 5900bd10 5c8f27d9 00000de1 40936d10 40093f64 59014e4c 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f34: 592d78ac 59014b98 5c8f33c1 00000000 3e828f5d 40852b50 40936d10 40093f88 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f54: 59022ec4 592d7c54 59014e4c 5c8f2ff5 40b2da68 00000001 40852b50 40936d10 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237): 40093f74: 40093fdc 59023338 592db3b0 59022ec4 00000000 40936d10 00000000 00000000 
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d0  42253333c4228b9f  d1  bf800aed4422675a
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d2  00000000bf8015da  d3  00000000c3b56ead
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  c351800000000000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d6  00000000bf800000  d7  44228b9f3f800000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  4420000043bc0000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d10 0000000040b00000  d11 0000000040c00000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d12 4200000040b00000  d13 000000003e980000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  d14 404fc0003e880000  d15 00000000427e0000
04-18 11:22:34.620: I/DEBUG(237):  scr 60000012
04-18 11:22:34.790: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(302): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
04-18 11:22:34.790: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(302): processMsg: ConnectedState
04-18 11:22:34.790: D/WifiStateMachine(302): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-2ms arg1=6 }
04-18 11:22:34.790: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(302): handleMessage: X
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):          #00  pc 0000e810  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):          #01  pc 0000e988  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so (glDisable)
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):          #02  pc 00011d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):          #03  pc 00041208  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod_virtualNoRef)
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): libc base address: aff00000
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): code around pc:
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): 81d0e7f0 d803d042 429c3b21 e043d174 5360f648 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): 81d0e800 d019429c 428c1d59 e007d16c ff52f7fa 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): 81d0e810 eb066803 f88c0c03 e0aa785e ff4af7fa 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): 81d0e820 18726801 7860f882 f7fae0a3 6803ff43 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): 81d0e830 f88018f0 e09c7862 ff3cf7fa eb066802 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): code around lr:
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): aff10c94 08bd87f0 e5964000 e5967000 e2144903 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): aff10ca4 1a00000f f57ff05f e5965000 ebffed97 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): aff10cb4 e2055a02 e3853001 e1500003 0a000006 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): aff10cc4 e5865000 e1a00006 e1a01005 e3a02001 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): aff10cd4 ebfffede e1a00004 e8bd87f0 e3a00000 
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): stack:
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb18  00000000  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb1c  002df998  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb20  00000505  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb24  002e1cf0  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb28  40093e50  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb2c  5e9bfb78  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb30  40093e48  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb34  40093e30  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb38  002e1cf0  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb3c  81d1a1ac  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb40  002e1cf0  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb44  81d096cb  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb48  002e1cf0  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb4c  00000000  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb50  df002777  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb54  e3a070ad  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): #00 5e9bfb58  5e9bfb98  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb5c  00000000  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb60  5e9bfc18  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb64  40093f14  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb68  5e9bfb78  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb6c  81d0e98d  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237): #01 5e9bfb70  5e9bfb98  
04-18 11:22:34.820: I/DEBUG(237):     5e9bfb74  aca11d38  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-18 11:22:35.000: I/InputReader(302): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
04-18 11:22:35.000: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40e02698 com.sttl.em/com.sttl.em.mainActivity (server)'
04-18 11:22:35.000: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
04-18 11:22:35.110: I/InputReader(302): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
04-18 11:22:35.110: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40e02698 com.sttl.em/com.sttl.em.mainActivity (server)'
04-18 11:22:35.110: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
04-18 11:22:35.550: D/BatteryService(302): update start
04-18 11:22:36.550: I/DEBUG(237): dumpstate /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
04-18 11:22:36.550: I/BootReceiver(302): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-18 11:22:36.560: I/dumpstate(7256): begin
04-18 11:22:36.650: D/dalvikvm(302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1714K, 59% free 17668K/42375K, paused 3ms+6ms
04-18 11:22:36.670: I/InputReader(302): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
04-18 11:22:36.670: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40e02698 com.sttl.em/com.sttl.em.mainActivity (server)'
04-18 11:22:36.670: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
04-18 11:22:36.800: I/InputReader(302): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
04-18 11:22:36.800: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40e02698 com.sttl.em/com.sttl.em.mainActivity (server)'
04-18 11:22:36.800: I/InputDispatcher(302): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
04-18 11:22:37.560: I/Gmail(817): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 8731, normalSync: true
```

Comment: Please show the log before the crash actually happened.

Comment: We also have seen similar crashes, and all of them are from Samsung devices.

Answer (score 12):

Actual error is **signal 11**, which means crash in native code.

If you're developing it as native app, your app crashed. Otherwise it may have crashed in Android's native library, which is less likely.

In debug log there're stack traces, which you may reverse map to source code line nubmer by gcc utility

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line -f -C -e libapp.so <address>
```

**Details:**

Interesting lines in your log are:

```
I/DEBUG(237):          #00  pc 0000e810  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
I/DEBUG(237):          #01  pc 0000e988  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so (glDisable)
I/DEBUG(237):          #02  pc 00011d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG(237):          #03  pc 00041208  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod_virtualNoRef)
```

These are pointers of functions leading to crash, top one is function that actually crashed.
In your case, you can see that it was in OpenGl library.

Further it depends if your app has native code, or just Java code. Since it crashed in system library, and you may be working only in Java, this may be indication of system/device bug, which you probably can't fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error in/after onAnimationFinished() on Galaxy Tab 10.1/Acer Iconia 500. There I called runOnUiThread(Runnable).
I fixed it by replacing runOnUiThread by handler.post(Runnable)

Comment: runOnUiThread just calls handler.post if the current thread isn't the UI thread, otherwise it just runs the runnable.